# Which parameters affect sorting of top reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I have reviewed 9 first-posts this morning and user **Anirudh Sharma** had 12 reviews at the same time,then I reviewed 3 posts more and as you see in the below picture we have 12 reviewed posts but I have higher rank in the top reviewer sorting.I think my rank should be lower. I'd like to know which parameters affect the sorting of top reviewers?

[image]

Comment: You're both tied on 12 reviews, not sure a secondary sort column is used or required. It might just be ordering tied results by the date of last review, but essentially you're still tied on 12 reviews.

Comment: Yes both are tied,but he was quicker than me.